# Colorbox Vimeo video not showing on production site (shows correctly on local version)

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, colorbox, vimeo

I'm using colorbox to try enable users to play videos on our site in a jQuery popup window.  I got this running in my local environment with the base colorbox example provided on the site.  It worked fine with no problems, so I adapted the code to fit our site.  However, when I pushed it to production, the popup worked but no video showed up.  I reverted everything to the very base example (provided here: http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/) on my live server and all the links/functions worked except for the vimeo and youtube links.  Again, these created the popup but no video showed (I used just the base example video links provided in the demo).

- I'm using the exact code from the demo page but pointing to my copy of jQuery and Colorbox and the jQuery code is working (colorbox popups show up, etc) but the vid isn't playing.
- I can embed a vimeo/youtube video in the page successfully without a problem (not using jQuery/colobox)
- Other jQuery functions work correctly
- It works on my local environment (vids show up and play properly)

Could this be a php or apache setting (LAMP stack) difference that I haven't found?  Any other suggestions?  Thanks!

Comment: What os are you running in Prod? Did you check your IPtables? Firewall?

Comment: Running Ubuntu.  Haven't checked IPtables, firewall is not the problem though.  If it was either of those, wouldn't that limit me from a normal embed as well? (I can embed a video and everything works correctly).

Comment: *Slight update - it actually appears to be related to the iframe usage - none of the iframe links in the demo work on the production version (but do work locally).

Comment: Where is the iframe content actually coming from? Localhost? Vimeo?

Comment: Apologies for the delay in responding.  The vids were coming from Vimeo (permissions were open there for me to access them).

Comment: This isn't really an answer to this question, but in the end I moved to fancybox and the issue cleared up. I was never able to hash out the colorbox issue.